# Sage 50 (Formerly Peachtree) integration question

Tags: theming, payment-gateways

I need to work on a membership website that needs to connect to a Peachtree database in order to verify the user's current balance. I've never worked on this kind of projects before and I am unable to find any kind of information between Drupal and Peachtree. Does the client needs to upgrade to Sage 50 in order to make this happen or can this integration still be done using Peachtree?

Thanks a lot!

Johann